# How can I filter a deeply nested map in a list?

Tags: dictionary, filter, elixir

I am working with the GitHub GraphQL API and have a need to filter down some of the response data, but it is so deeply nested. Below is a snipped example of the response that I am dealing with.

```
%{"name" => "repo",
  "pullRequests" => %{
    "nodes" => [%{
      "reviews" => %{
        "nodes" => [
          %{"author" => %{"login" => "FOO"}, "state" => "COMMENTED"},
          %{"author" => %{"login" => "BAR"}, "state" => "COMMENTED"},
          %{"author" => %{"login" => "BAR"}, "state" => "COMMENTED"},
          %{"author" => %{"login" => "BAR"}, "state" => "COMMENTED"},
          %{"author" => %{"login" => "BAR"}, "state" => "COMMENTED"},
          %{"author" => %{"login" => "FOO"}, "state" => "COMMENTED"},
          %{"author" => %{"login" => "FOO"}, "state" => "COMMENTED"},
          %{"author" => %{"login" => "BAR"}, "state" => "COMMENTED"},
          %{"author" => %{"login" => "BAR"}, "state" => "COMMENTED"}
        ]
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

What I want to achieve is being able to filter off reviewers based on their login. How could I filter off some of the maps in nodes to end up with the following?

```
%{"name" => "repo",
  "pullRequests" => %{
    "nodes" => [%{
      "reviews" => %{
        "nodes" => [
          %{"author" => %{"login" => "FOO"}, "state" => "COMMENTED"},
          %{"author" => %{"login" => "FOO"}, "state" => "COMMENTED"},
          %{"author" => %{"login" => "FOO"}, "state" => "COMMENTED"},
        ]
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not a valid elixir term in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the perfect use case for `update_in`:

```
map = %{"name" => "repo",
  "pullRequests" => %{
    "nodes" => [%{
      "reviews" => %{
        "nodes" => [
          %{"author" => %{"login" => "FOO"}, "state" => "COMMENTED"},
          %{"author" => %{"login" => "BAR"}, "state" => "COMMENTED"},
          %{"author" => %{"login" => "BAR"}, "state" => "COMMENTED"},
          %{"author" => %{"login" => "BAR"}, "state" => "COMMENTED"},
          %{"author" => %{"login" => "BAR"}, "state" => "COMMENTED"},
          %{"author" => %{"login" => "FOO"}, "state" => "COMMENTED"},
          %{"author" => %{"login" => "FOO"}, "state" => "COMMENTED"},
          %{"author" => %{"login" => "BAR"}, "state" => "COMMENTED"},
          %{"author" => %{"login" => "BAR"}, "state" => "COMMENTED"}
        ]
      }
    }]
  }
}

map2 = update_in(map, ["pullRequests", "nodes", Access.all(), "reviews", "nodes"], fn nodes ->
  for %{"author" => %{"login" => "FOO"}} = node <- nodes, do: node
end)

IO.inspect map2
```

Output:

```
%{"name" => "repo",
  "pullRequests" => %{"nodes" => [%{"reviews" => %{"nodes" => [%{"author" => %{"login" => "FOO"},
            "state" => "COMMENTED"},
          %{"author" => %{"login" => "FOO"}, "state" => "COMMENTED"},
          %{"author" => %{"login" => "FOO"}, "state" => "COMMENTED"}]}}]}}
```

`Access.all()` lets us iterate over all elements of a list while doing the update. This means if your top level "nodes" had multiple items, all of them will be filtered according to our logic.

<sup>Note: your code was invalid syntax so I assumed you meant to wrap `"reviews" => ...` in a map.</sup>

Comment: I have updated my question to be correct syntax, as I did indeed have a copy/paste error. Thanks for the answer!